# IR Remote using Raspberry Pi CM4

Tags: raspbian, remote, kodi, lirc, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I am working on the Raspberry Pi CM4 module with the Raspbian Bullseye image (kernel version:5.10.63-v7l+)
I have tried many IR Remote tutorials like LIRC & KODI.

[IR Blaster (LIRC)](http://www.piddlerintheroot.com/ir-blaster-lirc/)

[Infra-Red Remotes](https://wiki.libreelec.tv/configuration/ir-remotes#ir_remote_configuration)

Still, I am not able to get successful results.

I would Like to implement the IR Remote with all possible encoding & decoding technics.

Will you please suggest to me any working Application or Tutorial for me?

Comment: what issues are you having?

Comment: @Bravo : I was very unsuccessful in trying to create a .conf file using the irrecord command.
Will you please help me to know how can I create a custom configuration file for all types of remote controllers which may have different types of encoding?

Comment: I am fairly sure LIRC has been deprecated since buster.  You need to identify and research the alternatives.

Comment: @joan That's why I came here, Also I am referring to the following tutorial [Latest LIRC](https://www.instructables.com/Setup-IR-Remote-Control-Using-LIRC-for-the-Raspber/).
I am able to receive the signals transmitted by the remote on raspberry pi. now I am facing a problem with transmitting that signals using the tx pin will you please help me to solve this?